# iOS show specific leaderboard Game Center

Tags: ios, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

How can I display an specific leaderboard in `Game Center`?

My code is:

```
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];

    if (gameCenterController != nil)
    {
        gameCenterController.leaderboardIdentifier = @"leaderboard1";
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;

        [self presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
```

I want to display only "leaderboard1" but it displays all leaderboards. Leaderboard identifier name is correct.

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue.